# Once I select an option from a dropdown and then click another element the selection from the dropdown is reset

Tags: java, selenium, appium-android

The page has 3 dropdown menus the first two work fine, but when I select an option from the third and then try to continue by clicking on the next element, the option selected returns to being the default "Select"

```
CreateAppStep1.SiteType(driver).selectByIndex(1); //0- https://, 1-http://
CreateAppStep1.CMSPlatform(driver).selectByIndex(0);
CreateAppStep1.CMSType(driver).selectByIndex(3);// 0- Select, 1- Ecommerce, 2- Ecommerce with blogs, 3- Blogs with Ecommerce, 4- Blog, 5- CMS Pages
CreateAppStep1.BuildAppBtn(driver).click();
```

the CMSType element gets reset to "Select" from "Ecommerce with blogs" after BuildAppBtn is clicked.
I've also tried `CreateAppStep1.CMSTypeOptions(driver).get(3).click();` by creating a list of the options elements.

Comment: are you sure that all list web elements are declared as a Select?

Comment: yeah it's declared as :Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@nodeName='SELECT' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[@text='CMS Platform']]")));

Comment: I was talking about HTML code, if there is declared as a select